# UItextView font color is changing automatically to the tint color

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

I am trying to get dynamic tableviewcell with a textview based on textview's content. It does expand and does the job, but when I scroll, the detection goes off and the font color of the textview takes the color of the tint color.PFB the code and screenshots.

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomCellTableViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property(nonatomic, strong)NSArray *data;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ONe is here wihth some thins www.google.com",@"Two with soe phone numbers like 002-092-98-283 and link http://google.com,Two with soe phone numbers like 002-092-98-283 and link http://google.com,Two with soe phone numbers like 002-092-98-283 and link http://google.com,Two with soe phone numbers like 002-092-98-283 and link http://google.com",@"ONe is here wihth some thins www.google.com",@"Two with soe phone numbers like 002-092-98-283 and link http://google.com,Two with soe phone numbers like 002-092-98-283 and link http://google.com,Two with soe phone numbers like 002-092-98-283 and link http://google.com,Two with soe phone numbers like 002-092-98-283 and link http://google.com",@"ONe is here wihth some thins www.google.com",@"Two with soe phone numbers like 002-092-98-283 and link http://google.com,Two with soe phone numbers like 002-092-98-283 and link http://google.com,Two with soe phone numbers like 002-092-98-283 and link http://google.com,Two with soe phone numbers like 002-092-98-283 and link http://google.com", nil];


   // self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100;


    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.data count];
}

// Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
// Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellID = @"CustomCell";

    CustomCellTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[CustomCellTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }
    cell.header.text = @"This is a header";
    cell.cutomTextview.text = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}
@end
```

**CustomTableViewcell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCellTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *cutomTextview;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *header;

@end
```

[image: Initial launch detecting links]

[image: Post scrolling not detection]
[image: Settings in the storyboard]

Comment: I had the same problem because I was assigning the text to the textView in the viewWillAppear. I fixed the problem by removing the assigning from viewWillApppear and add it to ViewDidLoad. I think you have the same issue here because you are assigning the text to the textView in the cellForRowAtIndexPath  in this line cell.cutomTextview.text = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; . I suggest you to try to set the text only if it is empty. Add check before the assigning using cell.cutomTextview.text.length

Answer (score 0):

It is changing font color because you have enabled `**Detection : Links , Phone Number** '.

You can de-select from Storyboard or you can change tint color of UITextview  to some other color (blackColor).

Comment: But, I need the detection to happen.

Comment: Than change the tint color of UITextview.

Comment: I did change the tint color. The problem is detection is getting lost.  The links are no more clickable once everything gets colored into tint color.

Comment: Have you enabled Detection, check it ?

Comment: Yes. I have enabled Detection.Please read my question. Post enabling detection, while scrolling up and down, this issue occurs